# May we assume that this open is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

To prove that a given function is bounded on the interior of the closure of a bounded open set  $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq1$), may I assume that $V$ is *connected*?

Comment: I don't see how that would suffice. How do you propose to prove that the result for connected $V$ implies the general result?

Comment: This is what I was wondering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Connectedness is not relevant with the proof of your result.

Take for instance:

$f: [0,1] \cup [2,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ where:$f(x)=1$ if $x \in [0,1]$  and $f(x)=2$ if $x \in [2,3]$

The closure of this union is the set itself.

Also $f$ is bounded on the   $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$  which is the interior of the closure of the domain.

But $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is disconnected.